# How can I use old version of .Net in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, sdk

I want to use .Net Core 3.1 SDK but Visual Studio doesn't let me use it. In the independent compenents section, I have to select .Net SDK for running the program but if I select that .Net 6.0 installing immediately. How can I convert that into 3.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open Visual studio installer from start menu
- Select Modify from Visual Studio that you want to add
- In individual components select .net core or framework that you want to add to your visual studio version

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: What if the SDK that I am looking for is not available in the list?

Comment: How about other versions? For example, I want to work in Framework 4.6.x, and I installed all the ones available in the installer, but that still doesn't appear in my Visual Studio target framework dropdown, I only have .NET versions 5.0, 6.0, Core 3.1 and Core 3.0. Is there anything I'm missing?